# Obtaining a constraint from a boundary value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, boundary-value-problem

I am doing physics research and have come across the following boundary value problem.

I have functions $f(x), g(x), t(x), u(x)$ which follow:

\begin{align}
    \frac{\text{d} f}{\text{d} x} &= x^{2} t\\
    \frac{\text{d} f}{\text{d} x} &= \frac{x^{2} g}{u}\\
    \frac{\text{d} g}{\text{d} x} &= -\frac{f t}{x^{2}}\\
    \frac{\text{d} \ln g}{\text{d} x} &=-\frac{f}{u x^{2}}\\
\end{align}
subject to the boundary conditions
\begin{align}
    f=0 \quad &\text{at} \quad x=0\\
    g=c \quad &\text{at} \quad x=1
\end{align}
where $c$ is a constant.

Given $u$, I can solve for $f,g$.

If I enforce that $f=1$ at $x=1$, can this be used to obtain a constraint on $u$?

Any advice or directions to look in would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\ln g\right)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$ and use the formula already given for $g'$. We can also use eqns 1 and 2 to deduce $g=ut$.

Comment: That $g = ut$ follows immediately from the first two equations, since both $t$ and $\frac gu$ are equal to $\frac 1{x^2}\frac{df}{dx}$. Only three of your equations are independent (your choice which three). The other is derivable from them.

Comment: @K.defaoite yes- those facts are true and well-known to me. What I mean to press on more is the fact that an arbitrary $u$ function could have any value of $f$ at $x=1$, whereas I want to enforce that $f=1$ at $x=1$ and I am wondering if this can further constrain $u$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am only able to tag one user in my reply, but hopefully my comment is helpful to clarify my question to you as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$ puts a restraint on $t$ that $$\int_0^1 x^2t(x)\, dx = 1$$

For any such $t$, we then get
$$f(x) = \int_0^x s^2t(s)\,ds$$
and $$g(x) = c - \int_1^x s^{-2}f(s)t(s)\,ds$$
and finally $$\begin{align}u(x) &= \frac {g(x)}{t(x)}\\ &= \frac 1{t(x)}\left(c - \int_1^x s^{-2}t(s)\int_0^s r^2t(r)\,dr\,ds\right)\end{align}$$

How to directly express the restraint that $\int_0^1x^2t(x)\, dx = 1$ puts on $u$ is not clear.

Comment: Thank you! This brings me in a very good direction. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: One question, can you please explain how you got the limits on the integrals? I would think the third line would be $\int_x^1$ instead of $\int_1^x$ but I am not certain. I guess it would just be + instead of - in that case though?

Comment: You could flip the limits and the sign, since you appear to be interested in $x < 1$ (though since you never actually said so, I had no way to be sure). But I ordered them as I did because $$\dfrac d{dx}\int_a^x h(t)\, dt = h(x)$$ for continuous functions $h$. If you put the variable on the bottom, then you get $-h(x)$. And it doesn't matter whether the upper limit is greater or lesser than the lower limit. The notation is defined for both.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation, it makes perfect sense. Do you happen to know how I could go about finding the complementary function for $u$, that is, the function $T$ such that $\int_0^1 T(x) u(x)\,\text{d}x=0$? (If I need to ask a separate question, please let me know.)

Comment: yes, you should ask that as a separate question. But I will say there is not just one such function $T$. Even if you restricted yourself to only infinitely differentiable $T$, the collection of all such functions $T$ satisfying your condition forms an infinite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I have posted the new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789626/finding-the-complementary-function-from-a-boundary-value-problem (sorry if the change of symbols is confusing - here I have tried to tackle the same problem from a different direction)